# Measuring distance between two continuous distributions using their discrete approximations

Tags: distributions, histogram, divergence

I need to compute the distance between two continuous distributions. However, I have no idea as to what kind of distributions they are. I have a discrete approximation of the distributions. That is, the support is divided into multiple bins and the area of the pdf corresponding to each bin is given. Thus, the values I have can be thought of as a pmf (all non-negative values summing to 1).

However, the catch is that the bins are not same for the two distributions. Is there a way to compute the distance between these two distributions?

For eg, I could use KL divergence. But the values being sampled at different locations will cause a problem. I can circumvent this by resampling one of the distributions in accordance with the other by assuming piece-wise constancy. But I am looking for a more elegant measure which can compute the distance without resampling.

Comment: Having different bins makes this really hard. I guess one could fit a distribution to the bins. If you are willing to pick a particular parametric distribution, that would be interval censored data describing it. If not, then maybe getting a kernel density estimate, but I'd worry what the effect of that would be. I guess you could also use some kind of interval-censored non-parametric comparison between the distributions (e.g. compare Kaplan Meier/similar things with interval censored data), it just wouldn't give you a traditional distance metric. Btw. KL divergence is not a distance, either.

Comment: Thanks! I'm unfamiliar with a lot of terms you mentioned. I'll look into those.
Yes, I know KL is not a distance, but for the purpose of my work, it is fine.